# Is "confined" a good adjective to describe places like buses, rooms, buildings, taxies and etc. What are other alternatives?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

Is "confined" a good adjective to describe places like buses, rooms, buildings, taxies and etc. What are other alternatives?

For example if I say

> You should wear masks in indoor places.

it only includes inside buildings ([based on Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indoor)).

Does the following sentence convey the intended meaning?

> You should wear masks in confined places/spaces.

What are the other alternatives (especially an adjective + noun) to saying that?
I appreciate it if you could both suggest formal and less formal alternatives (confined seem formal to me).

At first, "confined space" seemed a very good choice to me but on the [wikipedia](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ziQtZ5fRXeHKpQGwR88bAMqcByjpVGTL#scrollTo=Pg1Cex_UQWuE), it has been written that

> A confined space is a space with limited entry and egress and not suitable for human inhabitants.

Comment: _Confined spaces_ is the usual expression.

Comment: See [*Air Quality in Airplane Cabins and Similar **Enclosed** Spaces*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=ventilation+%22enclosed+spaces%22) for another very common usage. Both "enclosed" and "confined" can imply anything from *restricted access for people, vehicles, etc.* to *hermetically sealed; little or no scope for even **gases** to move in or out*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confined space is a very good choice for places where you should wear a mask, or not do things that pollute the atmosphere. (e.g. use aerosols.)

You could use 'enclosed', or 'restricted', for the adjective and 'areas' or 'locations', for the noun.

I would say, though, that 'confined/enclosed spaces' is the best choice - it is neither formal, nor informal, and some other options could sound forced.